# How do I check whether a scanned integer is indeed an integer?

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java, I program in C# which is very similar, but I have some troubles defending my code in java.

I'd like to defend my code against illegal input such as string,char,special char.

I want every time an input other than int to STAY in the do-while loop(exact place marked with ?????????)

Here is my code, pretty simple, it takes numbers and calculates the minimum number,maximum, avg,sum.
If the number -1 is entered, either the program won't start or the loop would stop and calculation will be printed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variables
    int count=0;
    int sum=0;
    int max=0;
    int min=0;

    //Initializing minimum value for a reference
    System.out.print("Enter a number ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    if(number!=-1){
        min=number;
        count++;
        sum+=number;
    }

            while(number!=-1){   

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number or -1 to stop: ");
            number = scan.nextInt();

        }while((Integer.toString(number)==null)||???????????? (Check for illegal input));

        if(number==-1){
            break;
        }
        else {  
            sum+=number;
            count++;
            if(number>max) {
                max=number;
            }
            else if(number<min) {
                min=number;
            }
        }
    }

    if(count!=0)
    {
        System.out.println("The Maximum number is: "+max);
        System.out.println("The Minimum number is: "+min);
        System.out.println("The Sum of all entered numbers is: "+sum);
        System.out.println("The Average of all entered numbers is: "+(double)sum/(double)count);
        System.out.println("T H E    E N D");
    }


    else {
        System.out.println("T H E    E N D");
    }


    scan.close();

}
```

}

Comment: Hint: There is a `hasNextInt()` method in the `Scanner` class

Comment: `nextInt()` only accepts integers (throws exception otherwise).

Comment: `Integer.toString(number)==null` is thedailywtf-worthy ;-)

Answer (score -1):

As "Gendarme" commented, method "nextInt()" will throw an exception for any non acceptable (like character) input.

Anyway, if you still wish to check for unwanted input use a simple validation when getting user input.like so

```
if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
    number=scan.nextInt();
}
```

I personally don't like your logic,though
Hope this helps!

Comment: Is `-1` matching with this regex?

Comment: @Eric Blanc if this was helpful please consider marking it as accepted answer.Below you have commented that you'll be using this.

Answer (score -1):

I can propose to use try-catch block to have a possibility to stop your code with any entered letter. In this case you can use both positive and negative integers.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Store {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//  Variables
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;
int max = 0;
int min = 0;

System.out.println("Enter numbers or Enter any letter to stop the programm:");
//    A try-catch block to use any char or letter to stop the code and see a result
    try {
//  Initializing minimum value for a reference
        min = scan.nextInt();
        sum += min;
        count++; 
/*  A do-while loop to enter so much values as you'd like, while a letter will not be 
entered **/
        do {
            int number = scan.nextInt();
            sum += number;
            if (number < min) min = number;
            if (number > max) max = number;
            count++;     
        }
        while (scan.hasNext());}
/*  If a letter was entered you catch an exception to normally break the code and see 
a result **/
    catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
    };

    if(count!=0) {
        System.out.println("The Maximum number is: "+ max + 
                "\nThe Minimum number is: "+ min + 
                "\nThe Sum of all entered numbers is: "+sum+
                "\nThe Average of all entered numbers is: "
+ double)sum/(double)count+
                "\nT H E   E N D");
    }
    else {System.out.println("T H E    E N D");}
    scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will use the if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
    number=scan.nextInt();
}